# Evaluate methods from Project Academic Knowledge API

Tags: academic-graph

I'm using the [Evaluate methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-evaluate-method) from [Project Academic Knowledge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic-knowledge/).

If I search for `Composite(F.FN=='natural language processing')` it doesn't return the total number of publications for this query.

This is the query I used but I have to specify the count:

```py
r = requests.get(f"https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?subscription-key={key}&expr={exp}&model=latest&count={count}&offset=0&attributes=Id,DN,S,DOI")
```

Is there a way to do it differently so I can fetch the exact number of publications per query?